# Firefox sending Authorization: Basic header on every request after htpasswd login, can't be overwritten

Tags: http, firefox, http-headers, authorization, basic-authentication

I'm having an issue with Firefox where it's sending the Authorization: Basic header on every request after htpasswd login with the htpasswd credentials.

1. Access the site, a htpasswd authentication box pops up. I put in the credentials and view the site successfully.
2. Send a request with a custom Authorization: Basic header. On Firefox it's still sending the htpasswd credentials.

It seems like on Firefox it's overriding the Authorization header I'm setting. I noticed that on both Firefox and Chrome, after a htpasswd login, the Authorization: Basic header is set for every request. But Chrome lets me override its value and therefore I don't have this problem. I haven't tested this but it looks like we're having the same issue with Safari.

How can I solve this?

Comment: Same here. Firefox doesn't allow to override the `Authorization` header, whereas Chrome lets you change it. Internet Explorer (11) doesn't override the header, nor does Safari (9).

Comment: Looks like this issue : https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1064378

Should be fixed since firefox 46 though. You might be able to understand why it's not working for you by reading the entire discussion. Hope that helps.

Answer (score 1):

As said by KeatsPeeks, this issue is solved in version 46, with the following patch : [Don't rewrite custom Authorization header set on a channel by cached credential](https://hg.mozilla.org/mozilla-central/rev/075be35157dd)

From the patch :

```
+    if (aDontUseCachedWWWCreds) {
+        LOG(("Authorization header already present:"
+             " skipping adding auth header from cache\n"));
+        return NS_OK;
+    }
```